# Error with YAML deep nesting

Tags: yaml, nested

I wanted to create a config file in YAML that stores a few translations. To encapsulate everything, I began to nest the options.

While parsing the file, I see the following error:

```
Failed to read data from customize.yaml\customize.yaml: yaml: line 30: mapping values are not allow
```

ed in this context

The parser refers to the following lines:

```
contact:
  title: Contact
  form:
    name: Name
      error: Please enter your name.
    email: Email
      error: Please enter your email address.
    phone: Phone
      error: Please enter your phone number.
    message: Message
      error: Please enter a message.
    send: Send
```

Comment: You should nest things correctly, e.g. the descendants of form 'name' and 'error' must be on the same indentation level. What the parser actually refers to is that you have `name: Name` and then an indented `error` descendant. It's not allowed to have a value assigned to an parent element.

Comment: I changed it the following way:
name is the node and `text: Name` `error: Error message` are on their own lines but I get still an error

Comment: I accidentally made a collection with dahes instead of leaving them. Now it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the value as well as the  error messages to "belong" to the key, you need to make a list of two items

```
name:
- Name
- error: Please enter your name.
```

or as another mapping with two items:

```
name:
  value: Name
  error: Please enter your name.
```